# Some PostGIS functions explanations

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po, shortest-path

I'm trying to optimize a route SQL function and playing with some ST_* functions I found around.

But even found a good one, I don't want to simply copy/paste what someone wrote. I want to understand what is happening in underground. Yes, I know: RFM. but even reading [this](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html) I don't know why the function combinations can make one better then other.

Can someone help me by describing what each function is doing? Other optimizations will be wellcome!

```
$1 = source
$2 = target
$3 = k
$4 = directed
```

**Option 1: No optimization.**

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        pgr_ksp(
         'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM osm_2po_4pgr',$1, $2, $3, 
directed:=$4)
```

**Option 2 (faster): Explain `ST_Expand(ST_Extent(geom_way),4)`.**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    pgr_ksp(
     'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM osm_2po_4pgr as r, 
             (SELECT ST_Expand(ST_Extent(geom_way),4) as box FROM osm_2po_4pgr as l1 
            WHERE l1.source = ' || $1 || ' OR l1.target = ' || $2 || ') as box
            WHERE r.geom_way && box.box',$1, $2, $3, directed:=$4
    )
```

**Option 3 (even faster): Explain `ST_Buffer(ST_Envelope(ST_Collect(geom_way)), 4)`.**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    pgr_ksp(
     'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM osm_2po_4pgr as r, 
             (SELECT st_buffer(st_envelope(st_collect(geom_way)), 4) as box FROM osm_2po_4pgr as l1 
            WHERE l1.source = ' || $1 || ' OR l1.target = ' || $2 || ') as box
            WHERE r.geom_way && box.box',$1, $2, $3, directed:=$4
    )
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi @iant, my question is: what the ST_* functions are doing in both cases? The docs are a bit unclear to me.... if someone can tell me "You must get a box with ST_foo and do a buffer with ST_bar because foo-bar is faster than bar-foo" I'll appreciate...